# Error building clojure project with lein

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm not at all familiar with clojure, and I have the source for a project that I'm trying to build. The project has a project.clj file, which google says means I should use the lein build tool.  However:

```
$ lein compile #lein jar does the same thing
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate testui/core__init.class oCompiling testui.core
r testui/core.clj on classpath
```

I suspect that project.clj may be broken.  core.clj is located in src/com/foodient/semanticanalysis/testui, and project.clj looks like this:

```
(defproject testui "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]
                 [org.apache.poi/poi "3.8-beta4"]
                 [gate-clj "1.0.0"]]
  :aot [testui.core]
  :main testui.core
  :run-aliases {:test testui.core/-main})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set up a lein project and the name has that Clojuristic dash in it, like bene-csv (one of mine), then lein new bene-csv creates several directories and `./bene-csv/project.clj`. My core.clj is located in `./bene-csv/src/bene_csv/core.clj`. Note the dash is dropped in `bene_csv` in favor of an underscore.

As to your problem more than likely core.clj is not located where lein expects it, which should be `./testui/src/testui/core.clj`. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I've got the same error with another file now but I think I can fix it the same way.

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is that the core.clj is not in the right directory. It should be in the src/testui directory.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you should change references to your code from

```
testui.core
```

to

```
com.foodient.semanticanalysis.testui.core
```

The reason for it is that the part of a namespace before the last dot corresponds to a package name (this term comes from java and jvm)

You indicated that your sources are in:

```
src/com/foodient/semanticanalysis/testui
```

so the package name is `com.foodient.semanticanalysis.testui`

You should probably also update the namespace declaration in your clojure source files to match this convention (or move your source to `src/testui`).

Hope it helps.